# Connect to mysql localhost

Tags: mysql

In my new Ubuntu 18.04 I can't connect to mysql, from local host:

```
mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

I uninstalled and reinstalled mysql following [this tutorial (second and third method)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MysqlPasswordReset) but when I try to reset passowrd I get this warning:

```
sudo mysqladmin -u root password
New password: 
Confirm new password: 
Warning: Since password will be sent to server in plain text, use ssl connection to ensure password safety.
```

After this, I still get the same error when accessing mysql, I don't know if the warnging is just a warning but password was reset or not:

> Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Comment: In the first command are you entering any password? If yes, try hitting enter without entring any password. Actually, when I was new to Ubuntu and installed mysql, I encountered same problem. The password wasn't set for that

Comment: I tried that already with the same result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem yesterday.
I got it to work using [this solution](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-18-04). Just uninstall mysql-server and reinstall it following the guide.

You might be able to avoid reinstalling by entering mysql with

`sudo mysql --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf`

and change the password using the same guide I linked above (or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33991228/what-is-the-default-root-pasword-for-mysql-5-7/50305285#50305285))

Comment: It was as simple as running `sudo mysql_secure_installation`, I was following the steps in the second link with no luck until I tried the first link first :-P thanx

Comment: @Melebius this is marked as answer, so this was my solution. You may find additional ideas here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-18-04